# Error in a simple macro with foreach

Tags: macros, texstudio

I'm writing a simple macro for TexStudio which should replace in the whole document "{1.", "{2. ", etc. with "{". I tried the following code but I get an error!

```
%SCRIPT

options = "g"
scope = editor.document().cursor(0, 0, -1);
\foreach \i in {110,109,...,1}{

    editor.replace("{"\i,options,scope,"{");
}
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught exception on line 3: Syntax Error: Unexpected token "

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know texstudio but do you really need a loop here, not just  a single regex replace of  `{[0-9]+\.` by `{`   ?

Comment: Of course you get an error, the scripting language of TeXStudio is *not* TeX. (I don't know what it is exactly either but looks like JavaScript? Then maybe just go through some JavaScript tutorial to see how to do an integer for loop)